# Windows service doesn't write to MSSQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, windows-services

I've created a windows service, which is to store information into a database, but it doesn't in some reason. Code of the service is below.

```
public partial class Collector : ServiceBase
{
        private CancellationTokenSource tokenSource;
        private Task writerTask;
        private Writer writer;

        public Collector()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.CanStop = true;
            this.CanPauseAndContinue = true;
            this.AutoLog = true;

            string connectionString = /* connection string from config */

            writer = new Writer(connectionString, dataSavingIntervalSec);
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var cancellation = tokenSource.Token;

            writerTask =
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => writer.Start(), cancellation,
                    TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);

        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            tokenSource.Cancel();
            writerTask.Wait();
        }
}
```

It's the code of Writer, which I use for database interaction, I use linq to sql

```
public class Writer
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;
    private int _dataSavingIntervalSec;
    private event Action DataSaving;
    private Guard _guardDataSaver;
    private Task _taskForGuardDataSaver; // where guard works in
    private CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource;

    public Writer(string connectionString, int dataSavingIntervalSec)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
        _dataSavingIntervalSec = dataSavingIntervalSec;
        DataSaving += OnDataSaving;
    }

    private void OnDataSaving()
    {
        FileWriteHelper.Write("it works\n", "C:\\file.txt");
        using (var context = new MetricsDataContext(_connectionString))
        {
            IpAddress ip = new IpAddress()
            {
                Value = "0.0.0.0"
            };

            context.IpAddresses.InsertOnSubmit(ip);
            context.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var cancellation = _tokenSource.Token;
        _taskForGuardDataSaver = new Task((token) =>
        {
            CancellationToken t = (CancellationToken)token;
            var guardDataSaver = new Guard(
                actionToDoEveryTick: () => DataSaving?.Invoke(),
                secondsToCountdown: _dataSavingIntervalSec
            );
            guardDataSaver.Start();
        }, cancellation);
        _taskForGuardDataSaver.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _tokenSource.Cancel();
        _taskForGuardDataSaver.Wait();
        if (_report.Count != 0)
        {
            DataSaving?.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

I service successfully launches and write text "it works" to the file, but I cannot manage to store anything into a database. How can solve this problem?

I install this service running .exe installer as an administrator. MSSQL Server uses windows authentication.

The connection string I use

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=/*name of my MSSQL server instance*/;Initial Catalog=Metrics;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Is the service running under the credentials of a user with SQL Server insert update permissions to the appropriate database and table?

Comment: Yes, the problem really was in the user the service run under. I tried several users (I gave to all of them permissions to write), the solution was to run the service exactly under my own user, not LOCAL SERVICE or ADMINISTRATOR. So, thank you very much!

Comment: How did you exactly run under your own user? Don't you need to be an administrator at least to install windows service from a command window?